# Difference between lazy loading and eager loading in JPA?

Tags: jpa

```
public class University {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private List<Student> students;

    // setters and getters
}
```

In lazily loading when I load a `University` from the database, JPA loads its `id`, `name`, and `address` fields for me. `Students` will not load. When I call `getStudents()` method, JPA will then execute the query

`select * from students where universitycode=id`

Is my understanding of lazy loading correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. If you use eager loading on the other hand, JPA will proactively load `students` for you and return fully-populated `University` object.

Whether single JOIN query will be used or two separate queries is up to the JPA provider (EclipseLink, Hibernate...)